# Why is data being shown when screen rotates in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm facing this issue where the data I'm retrieving from an API, `https://randomuser.me/api/` at first compose it doesn't load.
But every time I rotate the screen the data updates.

First load
[image: First load]

After screen rotation
[image: After screen rotation]

View

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val userViewModel : UserViewModel by viewModels()
    private var userList: List<UserModel> = listOf()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        userViewModel.userModel.observe(this, Observer {
            userList = it
        })
        userViewModel.onCreate()
        setContent {
            ListUsers(userList = userList)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class UserViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val userModel = MutableLiveData<List<UserModel>>()
    var getRandomUsersUseCase = RandomUsersUseCase()

    fun onCreate() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = getRandomUsersUseCase()
            if(!result.isNullOrEmpty()){
                userModel.postValue(result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [State](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose) to ensure the data changes trigger recomposition of the Composable.

> If you use another observable type such as LiveData in Compose, you
> should convert it to State before reading it in a composable using
> a composable extension function like LiveData.observeAsState().

Changes to your code would be,

```
val userListState by userViewModel.userModel.observeAsState()

setContent {
    ListUsers(userList = userListState)
}
```

#### Why does it shows the data during rotation?

When rotating the screen or during any other configuration changes, the activity will be recreated.

More info on that here - [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

In most cases, you would not require data to be changed when the screen rotates.

If you want to persist the data even after screen rotation, move the code inside `onCreate()` in your `UserViewModel` to the `init` block, like this.

```
init {
    getData()
}

fun getData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = getRandomUsersUseCase()
        if(!result.isNullOrEmpty()){
            userModel.postValue(result)
        }

    }
}
```

If you need to refresh the data on any other event like button click, swipe to refresh, etc, just call the `getData()` again on the event handler.

P.S: Check correct imports are added as required.

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
```